# Easiest javascript library for making custom tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, tabs

I am interested in making a tabbed display on a web page I am working on.  I need to apply my own styles, so I would like to find a javascript library that provides very little styling out of the box and makes customization as easy as possible.

Features I would like:

- Specify the Image used for the tab.
- Tabs can re-size to fix the text inside of them.
- Relatively easy to apply my own styles.

I looked at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) Tabs but it does not seem like it would be too easy to apply my own styles if I don't use their tools to do it.

I also looked at [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html), which seemed a little easier to customize, but appears to require that you use fixed length images for the tabs.

Can anyone recommend a good js library for creating customized tabbed navigation?  Am I just making customization of the two libraries mentioned above harder than it needs to be?

Comment: Can I get an explanation from the downvoter?

Comment: jQuery UI's Tabs are very extensible. There's even a breakdown of what classes are applied in which situations. Styling is as simple as choosing the right `.ui-whatever` selector and setting the styles however you want. Just [check out the "Theming" tab](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Comment: Fair enough.  In my defense they say this under the theming tab: `We recommend using the ThemeRoller tool to create and download custom themes that are easy to build and maintain.`  Doesn't seem like they suggest going the route I am talking about above.

Comment: to get a set of tabs similar to what's shown on jQuery UI, the ThemeRoller is the way to go. If you want custom, build your own stylesheet. In the end `.tabs` adds some event handlers and a bunch of classes to whatever you've specified in the options. It doesn't explicitly set any styles. That's all up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a super easy walk-through to create custom tabs using jQuery, I followed it once and haven't used any other tabs since:

[Custom jQuery Tabs | Soh Tanaka](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/)

I know it can be tempting to often use libraries for something like this, but it is very straightforward and you'll know all about how they work, which will allow you customize them far easier than nearly other plug-ins.

Comment: Looks very promising.  Besides jQuery is still a javascript library ;)

Comment: I know :) I was just referring to more "specialized/specific" libraries and plug-ins. Anyways - I highly recommend this one though, as well as several of the other tutorials / walkthroughs on the site.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for the link, I'm sure I will use it quite a bit in the future.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery-UI you can easily change the styles with css, you **do not** need any fancy tools ^_^